# Using NuGet to share code across developers

Tags: package, nuget

I am using NuGet in attempt to find a better way to share and update packages to share across multiple developers.

I installed Nuget and after choosing the option "Manage | NuGet pakages",

I installed the package "HtmlAgilityPack" and noticed it put a packages directory in my Solutions folder.

So I assume if wanted to share this application with for other developers to work on, I had to add this package to my repository as well....

This is not exactly what I want as I prefer my packages installed in a more global location so that other applications can access them as well...

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was just added to Nuget 1.6.
See [Nuget Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Workflows/Using-NuGet-without-committing-packages).

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about other *applications* being able to access the packages, don't be.  NuGet is the central repository for this purpose.  If however, you have custom libraries or custom configurations of packages that you would like to share, you may consider configuing a custom feed.  See the following link for details on hosting your own feed:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/10/21/hosting-your-own-local-and-remote-nupack-feeds.aspx