# Using NuGet with TFS across multiple development machines (DLLs not copied across)

Tags: tfs, nuget, project-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using NuGet to share code across developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514640/using-nuget-to-share-code-across-developers)

I've recently swapped from managing library use by explicitly referencing 3rd party library DLLs that are stored in my projects in TFS in a 'libs' folder, to letting NuGet handle such project references. However, when I add a NuGet reference on one machine (for example to Daniel Crenna's [TweetSharp](http://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp)) the DLLs do not seem to appear after fetching the latest version of the project on another machine. But NuGet thinks they are installed so I do not get the option of refreshing the installation.

Perhaps this is easier to understand with some screenshots. (I'll include small ones with click-through to bigger.)

Here's the project references added by NuGet on the original machine:

[image: Screenshot from original machine]

and here is the corresponding screenshot from the second machine after fetching the latest version of the solution from TFS and rebuilding:

[image: Screenshot from second machine]

You'll see that the correct reference is in the project but it has the yellow warning triangle as the DLL is not available, but the NuGet dialog only offers "uninstall" not "install" nor "reinstall".

How should I be using NuGet in conjunction with TFS across multiple development machines?

Comment: If you're using the latest version of NuGet, you should have the ability to right-click on the solution and select [**Enable NuGet Package Restore**](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages). It may be a solution that will work for you.

Comment: Why not check in the packages folder holding the DLLs created by NuGet?

Comment: To reduce repository size ... i get it now.